# Running Proguard for a nested Android library project

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am developing one Android SDK whose architecture is based on slightly modified version of https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/.

Architecture in breif:

`Data -> Android Library that contains all the Realm, API calls etc
Domain -> POJ library that contains all the business logic
SDK -> Android library that contains SDK related screens and other business logic`

**Basic assumption**
I have added `Data` and `Domain` as compile(:project) in SDK. And I've written a proguard config in SDK project, which handles most of the common Android related rules and some of the custom library related stuff. My assumption is this setup is correct, where I would provide some SDK related rules to the developers and they will be able to use the SDK under their apps.

Now I have a class called `Configuration` in Data, which is singleton. I've added following rule for avoiding the NoClassDefFoundError:

```
# Common flags
-keepattributes InnerClasses,Signature
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
# Class specific rule
-keep public class com.company.android.data.Configuration { *; }
```

I still end up getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.android.data.Configuration" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.android.sdk.sample-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.simpl.android.sdk.sample-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-19 17:00:26.134 30554-30554/com.company.android.sdk.sample E/AndroidRuntime:
```

Any suggestions about how to fix this ?